# Problems with new Pi 3 b+

Tags: wireless

i am absolutely new to pi really floundering. I've written a wpa_supplicant.conf file that looks like this:

```
country=NZ
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="Your new Wi-Fi"
    psk="180928502831"
    key_mgmt=key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

The unit refuses to connect to my router. I have several tablet that connect fine.

I can use Realterm to ssh in (connected via an ethernet cable).

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: `key_mgmt=key_mgmt=WPA-PSK` change it to `key_mgmt=WPA-PSK` or remove the line completely

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using **Raspbian**. If you followed the instruction [Setting WiFi up via the command line](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md) then you only need `ssid=` and `psk=` in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` so just delete the line with `key_mgmt=`. If you really want to use it then you must use a correct statement as *@Dirk* also stated in his comment.

`key_mgmt=key_mgmt=WPA-PSK` **is wrong**.

You must use

`key_mgmt=WPA-PSK` but as said it's not needed.

If there additional problems then you should look at [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/79866).

Comment: So far so good. i've removed the bad key_mgmt line. When i use the VNC Viewer i can now see all the wifi networks but to access the board i still need the network cable plugged in. I was hoping to wirelessly connect. Why can't i o thi?

Comment: @AndrewHodson What board do you want to access? Do you mean the Raspberry Pi? The wpa_supplicant is configured as client. That means the RasPi can connect to your internet router. There is no way to connect to the RasPi wirelessly. For this you need to configure it as access point.